# 10 Terabytes of storage - Microsoft Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, storage, virtual-machine, diskspace

I want to create a linux VM that can accomodate up to 10 terabytes of data.  Not sure how to accomplish that on Microsoft Azure or if it is even possible.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/

Answer (score 0):

You create the storage separately from the VM - they have a data servuce known as BLOB service in Azure
Here is a link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/
 supporting many terrabytes is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

You create one Linux VM from image and then attach (via Azure portal, like [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-windows-attach-disk/)) 10 disks of 1TB each. Today 1TB is the max size of a disk in Azure. As for the VM, you will need to have an Extra Large VM in order to accept this number of disks (up to 16 disks for an XL).